# Compare and print data from two columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have an employee table(emp). Sample data from emp table:

```
emp_name contact1 contact2
Harish  123      123
Manish  345      567
Ganesh  678      678
```

And the output I want is like below:

```
Harish  123
Ganesh  678
Manish  345
Manish  567
```

Explanation: It is like each employee has two contact number. If contact1 and contact2 are similar
just return the output in a row but if in case contact1 and contact2 are different then return name and contact in two different rows as shown for emp_name "Manish".

Any suggestions on how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) over the selection of the two columns separately, as follows:

```
SELECT emp_name, contact1 AS contact
FROM emp
UNION
SELECT emp_name, contact2 AS contact
FROM emp
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hX6AE4ompvKsocGAqZw96V/0).

Note: if you want, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end to sort your rows.